# Waking up threads using QWaitCondition

Tags: multithreading, qt, mutex

My Qt application has a worker thread which processes new data when available. So far the worker thread used QWaitCondition to wakeup when new data is available.

However, QWaitCondition is only triggered when the thread is actively waiting via wait(). It may happen though that new data gets available while the thread is still working, or right before it runs into the next wait() command.

I am looking for something like CEvent in MFC, which "remembers" the new data notification at any time and won't wait if new data has been signaled since the last wait() call. What is the best way to achieve this in Qt?

Thanks,
Fabian

Comment: You could use QSemaphore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some other thread can fire a signal when new data comes in, you can implement a simple scheduler class to wake up your thread at proper time (using signals/slots as @ratchet freak suggested):

```
class Data;
class Scheduler : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

Scheduler(QTread* workerIn) : worker(workerIn) {};

Q_SLOT void OnNewData(Data* data)
{
QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
while(worker->isRunning())
   condition.wait(&mutex);

Q_EMIT startWorker(data);
}; 

Q_SLOT void OnThreadFinished() 
{
     condition.wakeOne();
}

Q_SIGNAL void startWorker(Data* data);    

private:
QThread* worker;
QWaitCondition condition;
QMutex mutex;
};
```

If multiple data values come in while worker is running, those will be properly queued by qt event queue. Scheduler has to live in its own thread. Signal startWorker has to be connected to proper slot in worker thread, finished slot of worker thread has to be connected to OnThreadFinished() slot.

Comment: Thanks. However, I do not think that I should need a dedicated scheduler for that purpose... sounds a bit overkill in my case.

Comment: @Fabian, It depends how you think about it, I very much into the concept "the more modular the better" - rather 10 small classes/functions then one big one. So as long as some functionality can be easily encapsulated, it is never overkill to actually encapsulate it. Dedicated scheduler won't be expensive on any resource, while it allows keeping all scheduling in one place and can be reused for any worker should the need arise, also would make worker code less busy.

Comment: your arugments make sense. I will mark your answer as solution. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

QWaitCondition should be used in conjunction with a QMutex

```
public void Worker::add(Data data)
{
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
    //add data
    condition.wakeOne();
}


public void Worker::run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Data data;
        {
            // no other thread will be able to trigger a wake while inside this block
            QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
            if(shouldStop)return;
            while(!hasAvailable()) 
                condition.wait(&mutex);
            data = removeOne();
        }
        //do something with data;

    }
}
```

this way if a new packet comes along the thread won't `wait` and `wakeOne` will not be triggered by another thread between the check in the while and the wait call

a better option is to use signal and slots

Comment: Thanks. That works if "data" is stored locally in the thread so that it skips waiting if data still exists. In my case gathering the data to process is more tricky and happens only after the thread has been woken up. In that case the above code would "forget" wakeup calls triggered inside the "do something with data" section, if I understand correctly.

Comment: >> a better option is to use signal and slots
That might indeed be the most simply solution. Providing a slot for getting notified about new data (bNewData = true) and simply sleeping in a while-loop while no new data is available.

Comment: actually if there is an event loop then you don't sleep since the event loop wakes itself up when the signal arrives. if there is no event loop then the slots won't be triggered

Comment: Although queued signal-slot connections are *always* preferable, this is a reasonable solution to the common problem of waking up workers implemented via the `QThreadPool` + `QRunnable` pattern. Since `QRunnable` does *not* subclass `QObject`, queued signal-slot connections *cannot* be used to wake up `QRunnable`-based workers. In this specific case, `QMutex` + `QWaitCondition` is probably the least insane solution.